# Display just specific json information

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am not very familiar with javascript. I will know how just to display a specific information

the result disply completly the json information but I want only the answer in

Thank you.

```
"fulfillment": {
      "speech": "Sorry, can you say that again?",
      "messages": [
        {
          "type": 0,
          "speech": "Sorry, can you say that again?" ==> answer
        }
      ]
```

my javascript

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>API Example</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var accessToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    var baseUrl = "https://api.api.ai/v1/";
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#input").keypress(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
          event.preventDefault();
          send();
        }
      });
      $("#rec").click(function(event) {
        switchRecognition();
      });
    });
    var recognition;
    function startRecognition() {
      recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
      recognition.onstart = function(event) {
        updateRec();
      };
      recognition.onresult = function(event) {
        var text = "";
        for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
          text += event.results[i][0].transcript;
        }
        setInput(text);
        stopRecognition();
      };
      recognition.onend = function() {
        stopRecognition();
      };
      recognition.lang = "en-US";
      recognition.start();
    }

    function stopRecognition() {
      if (recognition) {
        recognition.stop();
        recognition = null;
      }
      updateRec();
    }
    function switchRecognition() {
      if (recognition) {
        stopRecognition();
      } else {
        startRecognition();
      }
    }
    function setInput(text) {
      $("#input").val(text);
      send();
    }
    function updateRec() {
      $("#rec").text(recognition ? "Stop" : "Speak");
    }
    function send() {
      var text = $("#input").val();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: baseUrl + "query?v=20150910",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
          "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken
        },
        data: JSON.stringify({ query: text, lang: "en", sessionId: "somerandomthing" }),
        success: function(data) {
          setResponse(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));
        },
        error: function() {
          setResponse("Internal Server Error");
        }
      });
      setResponse("Loading...");
    }
    function setResponse(val) {
      $("#response").text(val);
    }
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
    body { width: 500px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; margin-top: 20px; }
    div {  position: absolute; }
    input { width: 400px; }
    button { width: 50px; }
    textarea { width: 100%; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <input id="input" type="text"> <button id="rec">Speak</button>
  <br>Response<br> <textarea id="response" cols="40" rows="20"></textarea>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

result

```
{
  "id": "2fc6a6b2-9fab-4045-b1cf-xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "timestamp": "2017-07-15T15:28:54.34Z",
  "lang": "en",
  "result": {
    "source": "agent",
    "resolvedQuery": "Could you tell me something ?",
    "action": "input.unknown",
    "actionIncomplete": false,
    "parameters": {},
    "contexts": [],
    "metadata": {
      "intentId": "c9376a7d-ab8b-4304-8c84-xxxxxxx",
      "webhookUsed": "false",
      "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false",
      "intentName": "Default Fallback Intent"
    },
    "fulfillment": {
      "speech": "Can you say that again?",
      "messages": [
        {
          "type": 0,
          "speech": "One more time?"
        }
      ]
    },
    "score": 1
  },
  "status": {
    "code": 200,
    "errorType": "success"
  },
  "sessionId": "somerandomthing"
}
```

Comment: Assuming `data` is the JSON shown in your "result" block, you want `data.result.fulfillment.messages[0].speech`

Comment: yes what I need to change ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server answer is a JSON all you need to do is call the setResponse function with the property you want, in your case speech

```
setResponse(data.result.fulfillment.messages[0].speech);
```

in the case you have shown the argument passed to the function will be: "One more time?"